# Getting HTTP element QUERY_STRING is longer than the (1024 * 10) allowed length in PUMA Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am getting below error while passing huge query string in AJAX.I am using Puma Server.How to fix this issue in puma server?

```
HTTP parse error, malformed request ():<Puma::HttpParserError: HTTP element 
 QUERY_STRING is longer than the (1024 * 10) allowed length (was 13692)>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to configure Puma to increase the max length for a query string. But if possible can you POST the data as JSON or Form data instead?

Comment: yes.Tried but no luck

Comment: Do I need to make changes in routes from get to post?

Comment: You would most likely need to change the route for your current AJAX request from GET to POST.

Comment: I am getting Curl::Err::ConnectionFailedError when I changed to Post.It is Taking long url now.Do you have any idea regarding this error? I am using savon client.

Comment: That sounds like it could be a separate question. I'd post a new question with this error and include the code where you're using the client.